# Does Strophe support message carbon?

Tags: ejabberd, strophe

I am planning to add in the message carbon function(when a user is logged into multiple device and send a message or/receive a message, it will sync between all devices) for a chat server, i am running on Ejabberd and using strophe.js...

I am wondering if there are plugin written for Ejabberd that i can install and also for strophe.js???

I looked over https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib and the github for strophe.js 
None of them seem to have plugins for message carbon. Wondering if anyone has this implemented before??

I have read that if it doesnt, i should treat it as a groupchat??? I am not sure why that would work??? And not exactly sure if thats good for the resources, and what if it scales up, would that have impact on the overall structure.

If it is treated as a group chat, then i assume each resource/session would be treated as a different user? Then when a message is sent into that group, all of those other session/users are updated, so even there are 2 users??

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd supports message carbons as default in latest version.

This feature is unrelated to groupchat and cannot and should not be treated similarly.

If you read [XEP-0280 Message Carbons](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html#enabling) you should see that sending a packet similar to the following is enough to enable it:

```
<iq id='enable1' type='set'>
  <enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:carbons:2'/>
</iq>
```

You may find also valuable information in [XMPP Academy video #2 at 27m30s](https://youtu.be/SbpFgdryyIA?t=27m30s).